# ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'canvas' in '/home/pegasus/Documents/Final_Website/blog/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build'

Tags: reactjs, canvas, gatsby, react-pdf, pdf-reader

When I installed react-pdf I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'canvas' in '/home/pegasus/Documents/Final_Website/blog/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build'`

I'm trying to render a pdf on a gatsby website. But for that I need react-pdf and it's throwing this error.

Answer (score 3):

**To solve this specific error, try installing canvas module first:**

```
npm install canvas
```

If you are using Next.js app router, another error might appear after installing canvas:

```
./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

To solve this error, you need to install 'raw-loader' module:

```
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

And add following code to your `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
 webpack: (config) => {
   config.module.rules.push({
     test: /\.node/,
     use: 'raw-loader',
   });

   return config;
 },
}
```

Read documentation for more info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

Comment: This question is about Gatsby and not Next.js.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas package doesn't come with arm64 binaries.

On Apple Silicon you need to:

```
xcode-select --install
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/include yarn add canvas
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you need to install the 'canvas' package as a dependency in your project. Here's how to do it:

You can install the 'canvas' package using npm or yarn. Run one of the following commands in your project directory:

Using npm:

```
npm install canvas
```

Using yarn:

```
yarn add canvas
```

After installing canvas package in some cases, you may need to configure webpack to handle the 'canvas' package correctly. If you encounter webpack-related issues, you can create (in case not exists) or modify your 'gatsby-node.js' file to include custom webpack configurations.

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, stage }) => {
  // Add a rule to handle the 'canvas' package's native add-ons
  if (stage === 'build-javascript' || stage === 'develop') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          // If you're using canvas-prebuilt, replace 'canvas' with 'canvas-prebuilt'
          canvas: 'canvas',
        },
      },
    });
  }
};
```

After following these steps, your Gatsby project should be able to use 'react-pdf' without encountering the 'canvas' module not found error.